# Jamod (modbus, Java) Master programming, why does it repeat the transaction?

Tags: java, netbeans, modbus

I'm on a project that involves using the serial connection (hence the Jamod) and coding I came across this

```
//7. Execute the transaction repeat times
//repeat =10 defined in point 1. (go to the source to read the code)
int k = 0;
do {
  trans.execute();
  res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
  for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {
    System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));
  }
  k++;
} while (k < repeat);
```

[Source: http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/serial_master_howto.html, to really understand the question I think you guys might need to read the whole example]

**My question is why does it repeat the transaction?** 
it doesn't make any sense to me since the repeat variable is taken from the args that are placed in the **main** and as the tutorial says, its optional. 
So to sum up, why is that repeat there?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because repeat is optional, it probably will be 0 by default. If you give it, the loop will execute exactly 'repeat' number of times. With the default value the code will probably only execute once (as repeat will be 0)

The do-while construct makes sure that you needn't do any magic stuff in the guard of the for-loop to execute at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, but playing around and watching the traffic with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which supports BTW. modbus out of the box and it was useful to see more trafic just to learn and understand, what happens. But in a normal workflow it is not necessary to repeat the transaction.